# How to import a WASM module in WASM (Rust) and pass a String parameter

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I want to instantiate a Wasm module from inside a Wasm module, following [this js-sys example](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/wasm-in-wasm.html). In the example, the `add` function is called which passes i32 parameters.

I've created a hello world function, which takes a string as a parameter and returns a string. However, calling this function doesn't work, as it returns undefined.

Normally wasm bindgen generates glue code which creates a context and puts the string on the stack. However, no such code is generated for Rust.

How can I load and execute the `hello` function from Wasm in Rust?

###### imported_lib.rs

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
 a + b
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn hello(name: String) -> String {
 format!("hello {:?}", name).into()
}
```

###### main_lib.rs

```rust
use js_sys::{Function, Object, Reflect, WebAssembly};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;
use wasm_bindgen_futures::{spawn_local, JsFuture};

// lifted from the `console_log` example
#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console)]
    fn log(a: &str);
}

macro_rules! console_log {
    ($($t:tt)*) => (log(&format_args!($($t)*).to_string()))
}

const WASM: &[u8] = include_bytes!("imported_lib.wasm");

async fn run_async() -> Result<(), JsValue> {
 let a = JsFuture::from(WebAssembly::instantiate_buffer(WASM, &Object::new())).await?;
 let b: WebAssembly::Instance = Reflect::get(&a, &"instance".into())?.dyn_into()?;
 let c = b.exports();

 let add = Reflect::get(c.as_ref(), &"add".into())?
  .dyn_into::<Function>()
  .expect("add export wasn't a function");
 let three = add.call2(&JsValue::undefined(), &1.into(), &2.into())?;
 console_log!("1 + 2 = {:?}", three); // 1 + 2 = JsValue(3)

 let hello = Reflect::get(c.as_ref(), &"hello".into())?
  .dyn_into::<Function>()
  .expect("hello export wasn't a function");
 let hello_world = hello.call1(&JsValue::undefined(), &"world".into());
 console_log!("{:?}", hello_world); // JsValue(undefined)

 Ok(())
}

#[wasm_bindgen(start)]
pub fn run() {
 spawn_local(async {
  run_async().await.unwrap_throw();
 });
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `format_args!($($t)*).to_string()`? Wow, that is impressive. Just use `format!($($t)*)`.

Comment: That's just copy/paste from this example https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/wasm-in-wasm.html. It's not really part of the issue.

Comment: I think that if you do not use the glue code generated by `wasm-bindgen` you should stick to FFI-safe code, just as if you were interfacing with C. That is, a `#[no_mangle] pub unsafe extern "C" hello(name: *const u8, reply: *mut u8, reply_len: usize)` or something like that.

Comment: But... thinking of it, the called and the callee codes live in separated WASM modules, so they use separated memory spaces and they cannot pass pointers to each other memory. This makes things more _interesting_...

Comment: The sandboxing of WASM modules is important for this solution. The loaded WASM module isn't from a trusted source. Using FFI isn't an option.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to rewrite all the auto-generated javascript code of `imported_lib` using `js-sys`. If you look into the corresponding `.wasm.d.ts` file you can see that the actual signature of hello is as follows: `export function hello(a: number, b: number, c: number): void;`. I was getting started with rewriting all the glue code but this turns out to be quite painful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really took me days to solve this problem. I hope it helps!
Since it's a lot of info to pack here. I will try to keep it short but If you want to know more let me know and I'll expand on my answer.

### Short explanation of why this is happening

This actually happens because wasm by default does not return `Strings` so the smart people at `wasm-bindgen` did something so when you run `wasm-pack build` it generates a js code that do this for you. The function `hello` does not return a `string`, instead returns a pointer. To proof this, you can check the files generated when you build the `imported_lib.rs`

You can see that it generates the file `imported_lib.wasm.d.ts` that looks something like this:

```js
export const memory: WebAssembly.Memory;
export function add(a: number, b: number): number;
export function hello(a: number, b: number, c: number): void;
export function popo(a: number): void;
export function __wbindgen_add_to_stack_pointer(a: number): number;
export function __wbindgen_malloc(a: number): number;
export function __wbindgen_realloc(a: number, b: number, c: number): number;
export function __wbindgen_free(a: number, b: number): void;
```

- You can see that the function `add` does match how you declared, 2 parameters and returns a `number`. In the other hand you can see that the function `hello` takes 3 parameters and return a `void` (very different to how you declared)
- You can also see that the command `wasp-pack build` generated some extra functions like (`__wbindgen_add_to_stack_pointer`, `__wbindgen_free`, etc). With these functions they are able to get the string.

The other file that the command `wasm-pack build` generates is `imported_lib_bg.js`. In this file you can see that they export the function `hello`. Here it's where JavaScript call the compiled wasm function and "translate" the pointer to the actual string.

So basically you would have to do something similar to what it is in the file `imported_lib_bg.js`. This is how I did it:

### Solution

In your main project create a folder call `js`, and inside that folder create a file call `getString.js`. Your project filesystem should look something like this:

```
mainProject
├── js
    ├── getString.js
├── src
    ├── main_lib.rs
    ├── ...
├── www
├── ...
```

And the file should have this:

```js
function getInt32Memory0(wasm_memory_buffer) {
    let cachedInt32Memory0 = new Int32Array(wasm_memory_buffer);
    return cachedInt32Memory0;
}

function getStringFromWasm(ptr, len, wasm_memory_buffer) {
    const mem = new Uint8Array(wasm_memory_buffer);
    const slice = mem.slice(ptr, ptr + len);
    const ret = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(slice);
    return ret;
}

let WASM_VECTOR_LEN = 0;

function getUint8Memory0(wasm_memory_buffer) {
    let cachedUint8Memory0 = new Uint8Array(wasm_memory_buffer);
    return cachedUint8Memory0;
}

const lTextEncoder = typeof TextEncoder === 'undefined' ? (0, module.require)('util').TextEncoder : TextEncoder;

let cachedTextEncoder = new lTextEncoder('utf-8');

const encodeString = (typeof cachedTextEncoder.encodeInto === 'function'
    ? function (arg, view) {
    return cachedTextEncoder.encodeInto(arg, view);
}
    : function (arg, view) {
    const buf = cachedTextEncoder.encode(arg);
    view.set(buf);
    return {
        read: arg.length,
        written: buf.length
    };
});

function passStringToWasm0(arg, malloc, realloc, wasm_memory_buffer) {

    if (realloc === undefined) {
        const buf = cachedTextEncoder.encode(arg);
        const ptr = malloc(buf.length);
        getUint8Memory0(wasm_memory_buffer).subarray(ptr, ptr + buf.length).set(buf);
        WASM_VECTOR_LEN = buf.length;
        return ptr;
    }

    let len = arg.length;
    let ptr = malloc(len);

    const mem = getUint8Memory0(wasm_memory_buffer);

    let offset = 0;

    for (; offset < len; offset++) {
        const code = arg.charCodeAt(offset);
        if (code > 0x7F) break;
        mem[ptr + offset] = code;
    }

    if (offset !== len) {
        if (offset !== 0) {
            arg = arg.slice(offset);
        }
        ptr = realloc(ptr, len, len = offset + arg.length * 3);
        const view = getUint8Memory0(wasm_memory_buffer).subarray(ptr + offset, ptr + len);
        const ret = encodeString(arg, view);

        offset += ret.written;
    }

    WASM_VECTOR_LEN = offset;
    return ptr;
}


/**
* @param {&JsValue} wasm: wasm object
* @param {string} fn_name: function's name to call in the wasm object
* @param {string} name: param to give to fn_name
* @returns {string}
*/
export function getString(wasm, fn_name, name) {
    try {
        const retptr = wasm.__wbindgen_add_to_stack_pointer(-16);
        const ptr0 = passStringToWasm0(name, wasm.__wbindgen_malloc, wasm.__wbindgen_realloc, wasm.memory.buffer);
        const len0 = WASM_VECTOR_LEN;
        //wasm.hello(retptr, ptr0, len0);
        wasm[fn_name](retptr, ptr0, len0);
        var r0 = getInt32Memory0(wasm.memory.buffer)[retptr / 4 + 0];
        var r1 = getInt32Memory0(wasm.memory.buffer)[retptr / 4 + 1];
        return getStringFromWasm(r0, r1, wasm.memory.buffer);
    } finally {
        wasm.__wbindgen_add_to_stack_pointer(16);
        wasm.__wbindgen_free(r0, r1);
    }
}
```

In your `main_lib.rs` add this:

```rust
...

#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/js/getStrings.js")]
extern "C" {
    fn getString(wasm: &JsValue, nf_name: &str, name: &str) -> String;
}

...

    let hello_out= getString(c.as_ref(), &"hello", "Arnold");
    console_log!("# hello returns: {:?}", hello_out);
...
```

That should totally work!

Comment: The general idea looks great to me, however when I try to run this in the browser I get a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: attempting to access detached ArrayBuffer` in `getString.js:16:30`.

Comment: @frankenapps that is weird.... I tried the code before I wrote the answer. Do you at least get the string printed out or is this happens after the string is printed out? Can you check that the functions called in the `getString` file have the names of the functions in the file `imported_lib.wasm.d.ts`. If you still have problem with it I can upload the code into my github

Comment: That would be great. No the error occurs before the string is printed (it is never printed actually). However I used `wasm-pack build --target web` and then ran the program in the browser so maybe that contributes to the issue...

Comment: @frankenapps. That might be...? maybe... If not, here is my [repo](https://github.com/SpaceComet/rmStack/tree/master/stackOverflow/06072022-wasm)